# Necessary and sufficient condition for the homology of CW complex to be finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a finite CW space.

> 1. For a fixed $n$, is $H_n(X)$ finite iff $H_n(X,\mathbb{Q})=0$?
> 2. For a fixed $n$, is $H_n(X)$ torsion free iff $H_n(X,\mathbb{Z}_p)=0$ for all prime $p$?

I tried to use universal coefficient theorem:

$$0\rightarrow H_n(X)\otimes G\rightarrow H_n(X,G)\rightarrow Tor(H_{n-1}(X),G)\rightarrow 0.$$

But here I need the term $H_{n-1}(X)$ which the hypothesis does not give any information about. How do I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Yes, since $H_n(X,\mathbb{Q})\cong H_n(X)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ and a finitely generated abelian group $A$ is finite iff $A\otimes\mathbb{Q}=0$ (try proving this if you don't know why this is true; for instance, you might use the classification of finitely generated abelian groups).  Note that $\operatorname{Tor}(A,\mathbb{Q})=0$ for any $A$ so you don't have to worry about $H_{n-1}(X)$ in this case.

(2) As you have observed, $H_{n-1}(X)$ will cause a problem here.  In particular, if $H_{n-1}(X)$ has $p$-torsion for some $p$, then that $p$-torsion will cause $H_n(X,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ to be nonzero even if $H_n(X)$ is torsion-free.  So for instance, you can get a counterexample by taking any space such $X$ such that $H_n(X)=0$ but $H_{n-1}(X)=\mathbb{Z}_p$ for some $p$.